# Is there a Python equivalent to MATLAB 'time' function?

Tags: python, matlab, time

I'm porting a MATLAB R2011b code to Python 3.5.1.
The original MATLAB code, which was written around 10 years ago, contains a 'time' function as bellow:

```
t_x=time(x,fsample);
```

The output is:

```
debug> x
x =

  -0.067000  -0.067000  -0.068000  -0.069000  -0.069000  -0.070000  -0.070000  -0.071000  -0.071000  -0.072000

debug> fsample
fsample =  10000

debug> t_x
t_x =

    0.00000    0.10000    0.20000    0.30000    0.40000    0.50000    0.60000    0.70000    0.80000    0.90000
```

I'd like to do the same thing in Python, but I cannot find any equivalent function in Python. (The function name 'time' is too general that it's hard to search on Google.) It seems this 'time' function returns 1000/fsample (e.g., if fsample=10000, then 0.1) multiplied by the index of 'x'. Does anyone know a similar function in Python?

... Please note that this 'time' function is different from the 'time' function introduced in MATLAB R2014b:
[http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/time.html?searchHighlight=time&s_tid=gn_loc_drop][1]

Comment: If you're porting from matlab - are you making use of any libraries such as numpy, scipy or pandas?

Comment: Yes, numpy and scipy. I have never used pandas yet.

Comment: If I've grokked your example correctly - I think you're after [linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) not 100% sure though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be simple enough to implement a similar function.

For numpy arrays

```
import numpy as np
def time(x, fsample):
    return np.linspace(0, (1000/fsample)*(len(x) - 1), num=len(x))
```

For simple python lists

```
def time(x, fsample):
    return [i*(1000/fsample) for i in range(len(x))]
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :)